# Error inserting a .php file using the require directive

Tags: php

I am pretty new in **PHP** and I have the following problem trying to define a required file into a **.php** file, I have done in this way:

```
require("../../common/define.php");
```

because the **define.php** is into the **common/** two level back related to the file in which I am inserting this **require** directive.

But this syntax seems to be wrong because it give me this error message:

> Warning: require(../../common/define.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\PandaOk\templates\default\common\remove-booking_pc.php on line 3

Why? What is wrong? How can I insert a required file that is some level back in the tree?

Comment: try this `require("define.php");`, or use complete path.. `C:\xampp\htdocs\PandaOk\templates\default\common\define.php`

Comment: `remove-booking_pc.php` is already in a `/common/` directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP current file:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\PandaOk\templates\default\common\remove-booking_pc.php

So then in this file you have a request for `../../common/define.php`

Which is two steps [folders] back, then into the `common` folder so;

This is two steps back:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\PandaOk\templates\

And into the `common` folder:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\PandaOk\templates\common\

So what you've given is a directory that doesn't exist, which is exactly what the error tells you.

instead, only go one step back:

```
require("../common/define.php");
```

---

Alternatively, and far better practise, is to do an absolute file path using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` such as *something like*:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/templates/default/common/remove-booking_pc.php";
```

This would mean that the reqire always succeeds regardless of where in your project diretory tree it is called from.

*(I don't know what directory your `document_root` will be defined as, but you should get the idea, I hope)*

---

You can also give a full static file path such [as commented by Sahil Gulati](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43781432/error-inserting-a-php-file-using-the-require-directive#comment74603109_43781432).

```
require "C:\xampp\htdocs\PandaOk\templates\default\common\define.php";
```

---

**P.S**: `Require` and `include` do not need brackets.